# i am not able to link my jsp files in web-inf folder

Tags: java, text

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>AddToItinerary</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>servlets.AddToItinerary</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AddToItinerary</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>AddToItinerary</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>`
```

// my class files are in WEB-INF-classes-servlets folders .while i am trying to access it displaying 404 error

Comment: What URL are you using (in your BROWSER)?

Comment: Please be specify whether are you not getting jsp or servlet ?

Comment: jsp pages is not opening.i am hosting website in cpanal

Comment: my button name is addtoitinary.if we click button it has to get the details from the database and it has to display in anotherpage

Comment: Addtoitinary is my java file

Answer (score 0):

Imagine for a second that your class is this:

```
package com.test;

public class MyServlet extends ... {
}
```

Then your XML will have

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>AnyName</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.test.MyServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>AnyName</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/any/path/you/want</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: in servlet-class what is com.

Comment: This is your package name

Comment: servlets is my package and Addtoitinary is my class

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the  definition which should look something like -

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddToItinerary</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>{Class Name with package}</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Also, seems like the url-pattern is wrong, shouldn't your `url-pattern` start with `/` ?

Comment: my class files in WEB-INF/classes/servlets

Comment: It doesn't matter where the class files are, what matters is the `package` statement at the top of the class file, lets say it says `package somthing.somethingelse.some` and class name is `SomeClass` , then the class name to use in the tag is -
`somthing.somethingelse.some.SomeClass`

Comment: my package name is servlets(package servlets;)   and class name is Addtoitinerary

Comment: so it should be `<servlet-class>servlets.AddtoItinerary</servlet-class>` .
Please understand that Java is case sensitive.

Comment: like i said, check the url-pattern, add a `/` to start. And how are you accessing the servlet? Are you giving - `http://<host>:<port>/AddtoItinerary` ?

Comment: i am hosting website in Godaddy(cpanal)

Comment: i am directly going to website like www.****.com

Comment: use - `www.****.com/AddToItinerary`

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>package.ClassName</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Url pattern</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**servlet-name** - Give your servlet name you want to give

**servlet-class** - Give the absolute path of the class like A Class is in package **com.test** then it will be **com.test.A**

**url-pattern** - Give the url pattern to associate a filter or servlet

Hope it helps!!

Comment: servlets is my package and Addtoitinary is my class

Comment: then it will be servlets.Addtoitinary, check your url, generally problem is in mapping url

Comment: url i gave as /Addtoitinary

Answer (score 0):

in the Html page remove the "/" from the action it will start navigating from the project folder along with URL.